# How to correct render data from array?

Tags: arrays, mapping, gatsby

App.js
import { useSiteMetadata } from "../hooks/use-site-metadata"

export default function () {
const { projectItems } = useSiteMetadata()

```
  return (
    <Box flex flex-wrap items-start mb5>
      {projectItems.map((value, index, category) => {
        return (
          <ProjectItem
            key={index}
            name={value.name}
            title={value.title}
            image={value.image}
            className="border-box"
            exerpt={value.exerpt}
            git={value.git}
            url={value.url}
            category={value.category}
            click="Push"
            sans-serif
            mb0-l
            mb3
            flex-none
            w5
            mr3
          />
        )
      })}
    </Box>
  )
}
```

site Metadata

```
projectItems: [
  {
    name: `1project`,
    title: `1 title`,
    image: `test-pic.jpg`,
    exerpt: `some first project`,
    git: `https://github.com/desmukh/gatsby-starter-woo/tree/master/`,
    url: `https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll/`,
    category: ["all", "mobile", "ux-ui"],
  },
  {
    name: `2project`,
    title: `2 title`,
    image: `photo-2.jpg`,
    exerpt: `some 2 project`,
    git: `https://github.com/desmukh/gatsby-starter-woo/tree/master/`,
    url: `https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll/`,
    category: ["all", "mobile", "ux-ui"],
  },
  {
    name: `3project`,
    title: `3 title`,
    image: `photo-2.jpg`,
    exerpt: `some 3 project`,
    git: `https://github.com/desmukh/gatsby-starter-woo/tree/master/`,
    url: `https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll/`,
    category: ["all", "mobile", "ux-ui"],
  },
],
```

site-metadata-query

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
export const useSiteMetadata = () => {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query MyQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author {
              name
            }
            sections
            projectItems {
              name
              title
              image
              exerpt
              git
              url
              category
            }
            favicon
            logo
            menuItems {
              path
              label
            }
            social {
              service
              url
              fa
            }
            footer {
              text
              logo
            }
            address {
              line1
              line2
              line3
            }
            contacts {
              text
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  return site.siteMetadata
}
```

[image]

How to fetch data from the site Metadata from the  the categories items array, so it will look like list of items, one by one. Now the problem is that data appear like one piece of data(like on the picture), but there are few items in the array. [All code is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-varahamihira-2c753?file=/src/pages/P.js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with querying and styling array metadata Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995623/problem-with-querying-and-styling-array-metadata-gatsby)

Comment: @FerranBuireu   it's my own question, i just minimize the problem i stuck.

Comment: That's why is duplicated. Try to clarify your previous question in order to allow people to help you.

Comment: Your problem is fixed by changing how yo manage the data. Instead of putting a raw object in a configuration file, you should make queries using `gatsby-node.js` but this requires a re-do process... You are trying to put patches and this is not optimal.

Comment: @FerranBuireu i leave only this question. Well the problem is that i'm not sure how to map through category array in site Metadata, and have output of all item like the list.

Comment: @FerranBuireu the storing data in gatsby-config.js works fine. It's common thing. Here you can see i got this from official Gatsby starter https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/desmukh/gatsby-starter-woo?d=gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll.

Comment: @FerranBuireu All other data is appearing correctly< the problem is only with category data array in the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221862/discussion-between-turok87-and-ferran-buireu).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was i didn't specify - how to  access the elements in the arrays that are within the objects. With different words - in the return statement that map all array should be second map with the return statement and indentation is very important. If someone faced with same problem - this thread is very helpful [same problem with react, but react with old version so be mind](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/use-map-array-stored-in-variable-in-jsx-section-react/281358/2)